# Name for the top/bottom "hemispheres" of a capsule/stadium

Tags: geometry

I'm designing software that extensively refers to the rounded top and bottom parts of a capsule/stadium. I will have to refer to contact points isolated to that area and it has to exclude the straight lines of the shape. I'm looking for a means to communicate this vocabulary to the user. e.g. "capsule is making contact at the bottom/top ..."

My best guess at the moment is "hemisphere" but that feels like sacrilege since the shape is nowhere near a "-sphere" and "hemi-" refers to "half", which will include the straight parts of the shape. What can I call this to be mathimatically correct or perhaps just idiomatic to the users?

[image]

Comment: Just came across the term "semisphere", would it be accurate to refer to it as the top/bottom semisphere? I am aiming for the surface area, not the entire volume however...

Comment: I'd go with _semicircle_.

Comment: Why do you say that the shape in question is nowhere near a sphere? To me it looks like a part of a sphere.

Comment: @YNK because I saw this in the definition for a sphere: "with every point on its surface equidistant from its center". Therefore a capsule can never be a sphere.

Comment: I think one or both of us are not understanding what the other is saying. Doesn't matter. 
Just tell me whether this object you are referring to as capsule or stadium is a 
2-dimensional or 3-dimensional object.

Comment: It's a 3-dimensional capsule. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: "is a basic three-dimensional geometric shape consisting of a cylinder with hemispherical ends."

And concluded the hemisphere is fact the correct term.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(geometry)